# Not able to see in look dev or render mode on macbook pro

Tags: animation

Despite my computer apparently fulfilling all the minimum system requirements to run blender 2 .8 when i change to look dev mode the objects turn completely black, when in render mode the objects sparkle with a kaliedescope of colours. As a consequence now 5 weeks into learning this programme i have not yet once managed to apply textures of colours and have not been able to complete any tutorials. Having real issues finding anyone who can shed light on this...thanks

Computer is a 2011 13 in Macbook pro 2.3ghz intel core processor with an intel HD graphics 3000 512mb

Hope this all rings a bell for someone as i would love to learn Blender properly.

Comment: if your system is too old it won't work fine unfortunately, so either avoid Lookdev and Evee, or switch to 2.79

Comment: The minimum requirements for running Blender are documented here (https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). The Intel HD Graphics 3000 integrated GPU does not fulfill the minimum requirements (Haswell or newer is required), however there are workarounds implemented in Blender that should allow it to run if you have a recent graphics driver installed, even though the hardware is not officially supported anymore. Try to update your graphics driver.